# resizing images as the image is uploaded asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to resize the image after it is uploaded to the database but i don't know how.
is it possible to resize an image that is uploaded to database with nvarchar(max) format or it just has to be saved as image format?
can it be resized before uploading?
I am using image upload control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a plugin from http://imageresizing.net/, which I then call from code-behind to resize images. There are some free parts and other parts you have to pay for. You can also get it from NuGet in Visual Studio. The resizing is handled on the server in C# before you store your images.

By the way, it is better, if you have many images, to store them in a file system or cloud storage account. Databases are not optimised for images and you might incur a large performance problem or high costs if you keep them all in a database. I keep the filename in the database and then store all my images in Amazon S3 storage.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it seems to be more difficult to use the plugin than write a ten line code for image resizing, isn't it?

Comment: Create a memory stream to write to, obtain the input memory stream for the image then just one line: ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(inputimagestream, outmemorystream, new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("maxwidth=1280&maxheight=720&format=png"), false);

Comment: could you please explain it more? sorry if this question seems to be silly,actually i have started coding for a few months...

Comment: is it the same if I use imageUpload control?

Comment: I'm not going to write a load of code for you. The imageUpload control gets the image from the browser to your server application and it arrives in imageUpload.FileContent property as a stream. You should check the uploaded file is actually an image etc. to ensure nothing bad is being uploaded and then pass this to the Build function of ImageBuilder. Docs are here: http://imageresizing.net/docs/managed

Comment: I have just written a blog post here: http://lukieb.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/resizing-aspnet-images-with.html that should help you going forwards but StackOverflow is not free training, it is to help fix specific problems.